# How to remove a line of HTML in webform?

Tags: webforms

The company I work for uses Drupal Webform to collect information regarding it's customers. At the very end of the webform, we have a file component with a size maximum of 64 MB. I was tasked with removing the description under the upload.

[image: Description Image]

Just to clarify, I don't want to remove the max size, just the text that says what the max size is.

Comment: Are want to change in all website or on particular webform?

Comment: are you using D7 or D8?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to your **css file** this style:

```
div.field-widget-file-generic p.help-block{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which Drupal version are you using, as you have not provided. But if I use common sense, it should be D7, as webform module does not have stable D8 version.

Since you want the **`64MB`**, it has to be done programmatically as that number comes from the code, so if you change tomorrow to **`32MB`**, it needs to change accordingly, and display on that?

This we can do the by overriding the themeable output, You need to use function [theme_file_upload_help()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.field.inc/function/theme_file_upload_help/7.x)

Copy and paste that following code in your theme's `template.php` file, change the `YourThemeName` with your theme name. save and clear cache.

```
function YourThemeName_file_upload_help($variables) {
  $description = $variables['description'];
  $upload_validators = $variables['upload_validators'];

  $descriptions = array();

  if (strlen($description)) {
    $descriptions[] = $description;
  }
  if (isset($upload_validators['file_validate_size'])) {
    $descriptions[] = t('!size.', array('!size' => '<strong>' . format_size($upload_validators['file_validate_size'][0]) . '</strong>'));
  }
  if (isset($upload_validators['file_validate_extensions'])) {
    $descriptions[] = t('Allowed file types: !extensions.', array('!extensions' => '<strong>' . check_plain($upload_validators['file_validate_extensions'][0]) . '</strong>'));
  }
  if (isset($upload_validators['file_validate_image_resolution'])) {
    $max = $upload_validators['file_validate_image_resolution'][0];
    $min = $upload_validators['file_validate_image_resolution'][1];
    if ($min && $max && $min == $max) {
      $descriptions[] = t('Images must be exactly !size pixels.', array('!size' => '<strong>' . $max . '</strong>'));
    }
    elseif ($min && $max) {
      $descriptions[] = t('Images must be between !min and !max pixels.', array('!min' => '<strong>' . $min . '</strong>', '!max' => '<strong>' . $max . '</strong>'));
    }
    elseif ($min) {
      $descriptions[] = t('Images must be larger than !min pixels.', array('!min' => '<strong>' . $min . '</strong>'));
    }
    elseif ($max) {
      $descriptions[] = t('Images must be smaller than !max pixels.', array('!max' => '<strong>' . $max . '</strong>'));
    }
  }

  return implode('<br />', $descriptions);
}
```

**Image out-put:**

> [image]

---

Now this will remove **`Files must be less than`** part from entire web-site.

If you want to apply this change only to that particular webform you need to replace the following code in above code,

```
if (isset($upload_validators['file_validate_size'])) {
    $descriptions[] = t('!size.', array('!size' => '<strong>' . format_size($upload_validators['file_validate_size'][0]) . '</strong>'));
}
```

With,

```
if (isset($upload_validators['file_validate_size'])) {
      if('webform_ID'){
    $descriptions[] = t('!size.', array('!size' => '<strong>' . format_size($upload_validators['file_validate_size'][0]) . '</strong>'));
 }
}
```

Note:Change the 'webform_ID' with your webform's ID.